# Implicit conversion from datatype 'TEXT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I am putting few insert queries in a stored procedure. The insert queries are independently working fine without any issues like :

> Implicit conversion from datatype 'TEXT' to 'VARCHAR' is not allowed.

But when the sp is run, it gives the above error for 3 queries. 
Checked all the columns, non of them are TEXT type. 
Has anyone has faced this issue, any clue would help.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we really can't help much.  I would double check to make sure that your SP is not overloading your VARCHAR.  This error will sometimes occur if you try to put more characters into a VARCHAR than the VARCHAR was declared to handle.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the problem is not with the stored procedure at all. The error happens when the input exceeds 8000 characters. SQL Server 2000 doesn't have VARCHAR(MAX), the maximum length for VARCHAR is 8000. So, if you try to pass a longer string to your sp, it need to do a conversion to TEXT, but it can't be an implicit conversion, so you need a parameter of type TEXT. Of course, you would need to change your sp, and there are many operations that can't be done on a column of this datatype, so you may be unable to actually do what you want.